# nginx configuration error: try to open a file which does not exist in sites-enabled

Tags: django, nginx

I tried to check the nginx configuration with

> sudo nginx -t

output:

> nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django1" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:60
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

I once created django1 but I removed/deleted this project. Now Iam trying to start a new project but cannot solve this issue. I googled a lot and tried to change the nginx.conf file but without success. Does anyone know whats going wrong here?
Best
alex

Answer (score 2):

You may have a softlink that pointed to your old project still.
Delete the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django1 file/softlink.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I just solved it with reinstalling nginx with this command: sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common